# Normal endomorphism caracterisation by norm equality $\|a^*(x)\| = \|a(x)\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Normal endomorphisms are exactly those that satisfy: $\forall x,\|a^*(x)\| = \|a(x)\|$.
From this equality it is easy enough to reach identity of the quadratic forms :

$\forall(u,v),\ \ 〈a^*a(u),v〉 + 〈a^*a(v),u〉= 〈aa^*(u),v〉 + 〈aa^*(v),u〉$

i.e. $\forall(u,v),\ \ 〈b(u),v〉 + 〈b(v),u〉= 0$,   where $b=a^*a-aa^*$

Now how to prove $b=0$ from there (i.e. $a$ is normal) ?

**Answer**:

As per Mason's answer ($B=B^*$), $b^*=a^*a^{**}-a^{**}a^*=b\ $ leads to $\begin{align}0=〈b(u),v〉+〈b(v),u〉&=〈b(u),v〉+〈v,b^*(u)〉=〈b(u),v〉 + 〈v,b(u)〉\\
&=〈b(u),v〉+\overline{〈b(u),v〉}=2\ Re〈b(u),v〉,\ \  \forall (u,v)\end{align}$

Thus, for $v=b(u)$ in particular: $\forall u, Re(\|b(u)\|^2) = \|b(u)\|^2=0 \Leftrightarrow b(u)=0\ \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a proof for a finite dimensional inner product space $V$ over field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If $\Vert A^*x \rVert = \lVert Ax \rVert$ for all $x \in V$, then $(A^*x, A^*x) = (Ax, Ax)$ for all $x \in V$, so $((AA^* - A^*A)x, x) = 0$ for all $x \in V$. Since $B = AA^* - A^*A$ is self adjoint (meaning $B^* = B$), $V$ has an orthonormal basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ of eigenvectors of $B$. If $Bv_j = \lambda_jv_j$, then $0 = (Bv_j, v_j) = \lambda_j$. Thus $Bv_j = 0$ for all $j$, so $B = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Small typo: $Bv_j = \lambda_j v_j$ not $Bv_j = \lambda_j$.